# How upload multiple pictures in Sonata Media Bundle?

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have installed Sonata Media Bundle in a Symfony 2 project but I have an issue. Indeed, when I want to upload pictures I can just choose only one. 
I would like to pick up multiple pictures, do you know how to do that ?

It appears like an issue in the official github of sonata-project: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/711 but if anyone have an idea to solve it let me know !

Cheers

Comment: If you like you can help to get this one ready to merge: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/pull/1105

Comment: I will do it thank you !